# I'm sending an Ajax request but I'm getting no response from my .php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I just want to state that Ajax and JQuery are really vague in my head so I'm still learning. However, I understand a little the idea behind just not the functionalities in details.

My example here is that I have this input type file :

```
<input id="photo" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*">
```

And I'm trying to simply send the file through Ajax request. Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#photo").change(function() {
            var file = $("#photo").prop('files')[0];
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append(file.name, file);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php.php',
                processData: false, 
                contentType: false, 
                data: data,
                success: function() {
                    alert("It was a success");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown:');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });

 });
```

Everything seems to work, the Ajax's response status return 200 but I don't feel like it's interacting with my php.

Here's my php:

```
 <?php
     echo $_FILES['file']['type'];
     echo "COME ON WORK";
 ?>
```

Is it possible that it has something to do with Same Origin Policy? I looked around and found similar questions related to it.

Comment: What is actually happening when the input is changed? Do you get the success alert? What makes you think it isn't interacting?

Comment: Basically nothing, I just get the alert "It was a success" and that's pretty much it. I inspected the console too and no information comes up...

Comment: When using ajax you need to assign a value for the response back from the php file. Try altering your success function as follows:    
success: function(xhr){console.log(xhr);}  
And then check the console to see what comes back.

Comment: Ok, i altered success function and got this notice **<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Boutons\sendmail.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Boutons\sendmail.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />**

Comment: It seems like I can't get the $_FILES information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the echos, you need to put resp in your success

```
   success: function(resp) {
                alert("It was a success");
                alert("PHP echos:" + resp);
            },
```

Comment: Awesome, this gives me back the echo it's trying to output from my php but the first line in my `echo $_FILES['file']['type'];`gives me an error : **<b>Undefined index</b> .... .... .."**

Comment: Forms send data based on names not ids, add file as name to your image perhaps?

  data.append(file.name, file); what is it's name :)?

Comment: It's not a specific name, it's based on the image I pick. But I tried serializing my `data` and I get undefined. I used `alert(data.serialize);`

Comment: @antHak If you use `$_FILES['file']` you need to have `<input type="file" name="file" ...>` in the HTML. Or use `data.append('file', file);`

Comment: @antHak You can't serialize `type=file` inputs.

Comment: And `.serialize()` is a jQuery method, you can't use it on DOM objects, it's normally `$("form").serialize()`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the information I'll keep that in mind! Your solution work fine for me now !!